# Azure DevOps Branch Policy Path Filter Not Working

Tags: azure-devops

I have a branch policy based on two separate folders but not every scenario is triggering the Required effect.

Here is the branch policy:
/DEO/; /WSOClient/Source/Legacy/WSO11-1/WSO/

1. Notice the space Azure DevOps is automatically putting after the ;
   I have no control over this.
2. If there are changes to the /DEO/ folder, the Required effect is invoked. Perfect.
   If there are changes to both /DEO/ and /WSOClient folders, the effect is invoked. Again, Perfect.
   BUT, if there are changes only to /WSOClient folder, the Required effect is NOT INVOKED.

**Summary, when only the 2nd folder of a branch policy has changes, Required is not triggered.**

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved.
We have a custom status, which ALSO required both of the same paths.
So, the build was being triggered for changes in both folders, but since the status only had the /DEO/* path, it wasn't requiring the /WSOClient/... folder to be successfull for the Pull Request.